# Limit number of user logins in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a user login named 'manager' currently logged in PC1, I want to prevent this user from login in PC2. So I created a trigger, and I got an error

> Msg 4621, Level 16, State 10, Line 2
>   Permissions at the server scope can only be granted when the current database is master

It works well if I use database master, but I want to use database `Employee`. How can I fix it?

```
USE Employee;
GO

GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO manager;
GO

CREATE TRIGGER connection_limit_trigger2
ON ALL SERVER WITH EXECUTE AS 'manager'
FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN
IF ORIGINAL_LOGIN()= 'manager' AND
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
            WHERE is_user_process = 1 AND
                original_login_name = 'manager') > 2
    ROLLBACK;
END;
```

Comment: You can't.  You have to use the `master` database.  I think the message is clear.  However, this is referring to the `grant` statement, not to the trigger itself.

Comment: Are you using Windows authentication or SQL Server authentication? Are PC1 and PC2 a SQL Server instance or a domain?

Comment: I endorse what @Gordon Linoff said.  Also, nicomp's questions are relevant.  My own take on this is that you may wish to consider limiting access through another mechanism like a proxy server that sits between the user and the database, or if this is a three tier application - in the application tier.  Doing this in the database may not be the best route.  Good luck.

Comment: @ncomp I am using client & server, PC1 and PC2 are clients. @ Ken Clement Do you have another way to limit user login?, I dont care about database, just focus on limit number of user login.

Answer (score 1):

Logon triggers are special. Not going too far into it, they must exist in the master database and not any other, thus the answer to your question is: "It can't."

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx

-Sean